# Wordpress showing image as thumbnail without using thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm currently working with a wordpress theme, where the homepage is set to show all the latest posts. All my posts are showing thumbnails, even tho i dont set an featured image in my posts.

It takes the first image in my post, and use it for thumbnail, but i dont want it to do that. The thumbnail should only be shown when i set it as featured image in a post.

So my question is: How can i remove the function that automatically shows the first image as thumbnail, and make it use my featured image in my posts.

Link to my website: http://bruunoggejl.dk

Thank you!

Comment: I ran into another problem now. I'd like the post thumbnails on my frontpage, to show in  100% width. They are currently showing in 35%. When i'm editing the css and make it to 100%, the images sure are showing in 100% width, but the image the resolution doesn't scale up with. It's like wordpress is trying to make a 150x150 image thumbnail, show as a 700x700 image. It looks terrible.

I have tried a few things but it either seems to break my site, or not doing anything.

Any suggestions? All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `get_the_image` function

```
get_the_image( array( 'meta_key' => ...
```

For `the_post_thumbnail` function:

```
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```

Comment: Thank you very much Maarten, just what i was looking for :-)

Comment: You're welcome, please vote up my answer :)

Comment: @KasperTangHøjriis please see ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I really want to vote up, and i have already tried. But i don't have enough reputation to vote up..

And yes i do know it's only decent to vote up, and show other members that i have found a solid solution, but it's not easy without the reputation :-)